# check code signature from unix

Tags: perl, unix, code-signing, signtool

Does anyone know if there's a way to validate the signature of a Windows program under Unix? In a similar way like with [signtool](http://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/windows/desktop/aa388171%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) under Windows?

Thanks in advance!
T.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I validate digital signatures for Microsoft's Portable Executable format in portable code?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6513752/how-can-i-validate-digital-signatures-for-microsofts-portable-executable-format)

Comment: Thank you for pointing to this thread.

Answer (score 0):

There are different signature algorithm possible, and Windows could have written their own in which case you might be out of luck.

You can use "md5" or "sum". You could validate the code in Windows and if validated, calculates it's "md5" signature and use that for Unix (and from that point, also use if for Windows if you want).

I would first investigate what kind of algorithm that windows tool uses, then you could see if the equivalent is available under Unix. If it is not MS proprietary code, a Unix equivalent likely already exists.

Comment: Nah. The thread to which nwellnhof pointed in his comment above is exactly about this problem. And no: if I validate the code in Windows first, I have to have a Windows machine for that. My question was aiming at how to do that without using a Windows OS.