# How can I find the public key of any PE file?

Tags: java, android, portable-executable

I want to verify the digital signature of any PE file (exe, dll) in Java. So, I need to find the public key and the signature of these files. Can you please help ?!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's a good discussion [here](http://badishi.com/windows-authenticode-pkcs-7-and-x-509-certificates/), which will be easier to understand if you have a background on the PE file format (there's a good intro [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc301805.aspx)) but to summarise:

- There's a pointer at offset 24 in the file header to the PE header
- The PE header is 116 bytes long and is immediately followed by the data directory
- There's a pointer at offset 32 of the data directory to the start of the security data
- The security data is an array of resource objects, each of which contains an ASN.1 encoded certificate
- The resource object consists of a length field (4 bytes), a version number (2 bytes), a certificate type field (2 bytes), then the raw data of the certificate

Comment: Thank @Jules.Can you answer for me the question: "Can I use java for verify digital signature certificate of PE file?" ?

Comment: It should be possible, yes.  It would involve digging further into the specification than I have done so far in order to work out what is included in the signature and what isn't, but it shouldn't be too difficult to figure out how to do this.  Once this is done, you'd just need to push the relevant parts through the appropriate hash implementation, and check the signature using the standard javax.security interfaces (as explained here: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/security/apisign/versig.html)

Comment: You may find the additional info in this question helpful: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6513752/how-can-i-validate-digital-signatures-for-microsofts-portable-executable-format?rq=1